# Making the mouse cursor disappear?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse-cursor

On windows, what is the shortcut key that makes the mouse cursor disappear?

I used to know this combination but now I can't find it.

When you press it, the cursor completely disappears, even if you move the mouse. it only comes back again when you press something else.

Anyone?

Comment: I don't know of a keyboard shortcut to hide the mouse pointer anywhere in Windows. Maybe you remember a keyboard shortcut from a particular application like [PowerPoint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/presentation-keyboard-shortcuts-for-powerpoint-2007-HP010154712.aspx)?

Comment: There isn't such a shortcut according to the [Windows documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/126449/keyboard-shortcuts-for-windows).  You'll need to use a third-party program, or just use the functionality noted in @Richard's [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/162938/making-the-mouse-cursor-disappear/162962#162962).

Comment: For anyone wanting to hide the cursor constantly (rather than when typing), there's various sites offering a `invisible.cur` file you can use - set all pointers to that file in control panel to hide the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

[Not sure how many Windows versions this goes back.]

In the Mouse control panel applet on the Pointer Options tag there is "hide pointer while typing", and if selected no special keypress is needed.

Comment: If you read the question you'll realize that this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something that will make the cursor disappear **Even if you move the mouse**. have a downvote.

Comment: I just hate it when people write something only vaguely tangential to the question just for the slim chance of picking a random upvote.

Comment: @shoosh If you're unhappy with the relevance of the answer, edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @shoosh The silly part is that this answer's correct, as much as one can be.  Microsoft's Windows documentation lists shortcuts, and none of them for any recent version discuss hiding the mouse.  The closest thing is hiding while typing, which is the best answer to your question since it technically _is_ keyboard input that results in the pointer disappearing.  Downvoted your question because it's based on a factually incorrect premise.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the shortcut keys, but [nomousy](https://www.google.com/search?q=nomousy) has such a function.

Comment: Please don't link directly to donwnloads. But instead to pages that include them

Comment: @A Dwarf, What if a file has no page?

Comment: Say that it's a direct download?

Comment: The original link is dead. I did not want to link a non-official web copy, so I queued an edit for a google search instead.